# Same database and domain(single db instance & Single site url) needs to use by different organizations?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

My product will be used by different organizations.Each organization having multiple users.One organization data should not be accessed by another organization users(not at all relation with one organization to another organization).For this situation,I know we can create separate database for each organization.

But,I want to use same database(single instance) to handle multiple organization data.Is it possible? Product developed by `ASP.NetMVC` with `sql server`.

Thanks
Sella

Comment: I assume each organisation having different set of tables to access data. you can utilize user access control strategies in sql server . check the below link. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1138/giving-and-removing-permissions-in-sql-server/

Comment: there are numerous ways to handle this situation..question is a broad one..

Comment: *Why* do you want to use only one database? What if a customer calls you and tells you they messed up, deleted a lot of data, could you please restore from backup? What then?

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what you are asking for

BUT

If you mean that you want to use a single database File then It would be a matter of design in your database tables . You could achieve this requirement by using such a design :

1- Create a Table that would contain all organizations with the following   Schema :

```
   Id      OrganizationName
   ------------------------
   1       Microsoft
   2       Google
```

2- In your `Users` table which contains UserId and Password for logging into your application add a column with the name OrganizationId that would be a foreign key to the table you have created in number one . Your `Users` Table then would look like :

```
Id       UserName     Password          OrganizationId
------------------------------------------------------
1         admin         123                  1
2         James         12                   1
3         John          3213                 2
```

In this way when a user logs into your application you could know which organization he is working for and you would consider this in your queries

3- In each table of your database add a column with the name OrganizationId that would be a foreign key to the table you have created in number one . For example for an Employee table :

```
Id     Name       Address          OrganizationId
---------------------------------------------------------
1     John          sampledata               1
```

this `OrganizationId` column would be used in your queries as I will explain

4- In your Application And anywhere else (database stored procedures , webservices & …) when you want to insert , modify or retrieve data , consider the Logged in Users `OrganizationId` to do your operations . For example if you want to query to retrieve all employees working in the organization of a logged in User It would be like :

```
select * from Employee where OrganizationId = (select OrganizationId from Users where Id=CurrentUserId)
```

where CurrentUserId is the Logged in users Id which you could have maintained in a session or ... according to your application

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more about table for Configuration Data?Application will be access by multiple users from multiple organization at same time.All organization will be use same database ,same tables not different set of tables.

Comment: We are going to host this application on Amazon(AWS) EC2 server.Only one common database will be run from Amazon RDS for all organization.Because we are planning to release demo version of our product in cloud.There is one landing page, Client can register with their organization name.Then,they can able to access our demo version without related on another organization data.Isolated data should be maintain in same database for different organization.

Comment: @Sella I edited my answer to satisfy your requirement . In the edited answer there is no table as ConfigurationData anymore . that's because you mentioned that your data would be accessed concurrently by different users from different organizations

Comment: Thanks Karama,I understood what you are explaining.Instead of that can we use asp.net membership provider or Multitenancy concept?because we are using asp.net membership provider for login process.